# Calculate variable based on criteria in r

Tags: r

How can i add a new column to my data frame that would take into consideration some criteria such as:

```
ID AGE PERNO
1   30   1
1   25   2
2   25   1
2   24   2
2   3    3
3   65   1
3   55   2
```

to end with a table like:

```
ID AGE PERNO AGE_HEAD
1   30   1      30 
1   25   2      30
2   25   1      25
2   24   2      25
2   3    3      25 
3   65   1      65
3   55   2      65
```

Pretty much have the age of perno one in all the rows related to the id

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried?

Comment: I tried to use an if statement but Im not sure how they work in r

Comment: What's the algorithm you are using? I mean, what's the relationship between `$ID`, `$AGE`, `$PERNO` and `AGE_HEAD`? It's friday...

Comment: For future reference, you'll get better help if you can include a clear description of the problem and a reproducible example. Ideally, an example input, a description of the problem/goal, and an example of the intended output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plyr solution:

```
 library(plyr)
 ddply(df,.(ID),transform,AGE_HEAD=head(AGE,1))
```

OR

```
ddply(df,.(ID),transform,AGE_HEAD=AGE[PERNO==1])

ID AGE PERNO AGE_HEAD
1  1  30     1       30
2  1  25     2       30
3  2  25     1       25
4  2  24     2       25
5  2   3     3       25
6  3  65     1       65
7  3  55     2       65
```

data.table solution:

```
library(data.table)
DT<-data.table(df)

DT[, AGE_HEAD := AGE[PERNO==1], by="ID"]
   ID AGE PERNO AGE_HEAD
1:  1  30     1       30
2:  1  25     2       30
3:  2  25     1       25
4:  2  24     2       25
5:  2   3     3       25
6:  3  65     1       65
7:  3  55     2       65
```

Comment: Why not use `:=` ? Simpler. Faster.

Comment: @Matthew: Where should I do that?

Comment: No problem. `:=` adds the column by reference, by group. You can add multiple columns in one query. And `DT[, col:=NULL]` removes the column instantly by reference no matter how large the table is.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, what you want is choosing the value of `AGE` for each level of `ID` when `PERNO` is 1 which in this example is the same (by chance) as taking just the maximum value of `AGE`, if I'm not wrong, this code is what are after.

```
> transform(df, AGE_HEAD=rep(df$AGE[df$PERNO==1], rle(df$ID)$lengths))
  ID AGE PERNO AGE_HEAD
1  1  30     1       30
2  1  25     2       30
3  2  25     1       25
4  2  24     2       25
5  2   3     2       25
6  3  65     1       65
7  3  55     2       65
```